# Substitute variable value in double quotes

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim CodePan As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim S As String
Dim x As String
x = showSheet
Set CodePan = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").CodeModule
S = _
   "Sub ABCx ()" & vbNewLine & _
   " MsgBox ""Hello World"",vbOkOnly" & vbNewLine & _
   "End Sub" & vbNewLine  
With CodePan
    .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, S
End With
```

I am inserting some code in the other module  from one module.
Here i have a problem i would like have my sub name as ABCshowSheet for that i added as ABCx but because of the S variable in the double quotes it is coming as ABCx instead of ABCshowSheet is there any way i can substitute the value of variable even though it is in double quotes

Comment: You are not indenting your code!

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a problem in string substitution:

```
S = Replace(S,"ABCx", "ABC" & x)
```

I did it this way (instead of the simpler `Replace(S,"x",x)`) to guard against potential bugs if the code is later modified in such a way that the symbol `x` would appear in another context in the string. I'm not sure why you have a space in `S` before the `()` in `ABCx ()`.

Comment: Hi john, Thanks for the help. Sorry space is my typing mistake.